# Video cards and hardware-accelerated operations on double

Tags: glsl

Good day to all!

I am trying to use computational shaders (GLSL) to speed up some geodetic calculations. I recently got an experience showing that FP32 (float) accuracy is not enough. In trying to enable (with special commands) "double mode", I learned that consumer gaming video cards, mostly, but not always (examples?), do not have hardware acceleration of operations on FP64 - the compiler just shows an error.I found out that professional video cards are just designed for such cases.

Please tell me how it works? I just insert some NVidia Quadro or Radeon PRO into the computer, install the appropriate drivers, and I can safely compile the same program with operations on FP64, and the compiler will not show errors, right?

Comment: not sure how it is with new cards but on older ones in my experience F64 is there (at least 14 years now) but on really old HW you have to explicitly enable it in shader start however there are not used for interpolators and also precision of some math functions are different (and also its not the same if you use them in Vertex or Fragment) however as you use compute shaders its entire olther topic ... you could copy double math function implementations from any math lib and use those instead of th inbuild ones .... speed of F64 is usually twice as slow than F32 (on HW I work with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I learned that consumer gaming video cards, mostly, but not always (examples?), do not have hardware acceleration of operations on FP64

I would advise you to cease listening to whatever source you "learned" this from. It was either over a decade out-of-date (double-precision has been a required feature since OpenGL 4.0) or it is far too unreliable to bother with.

Now, there is always a difference between supported and *well* supported. Basically every desktop GPU made within the last 10 years can do double-precision math in shaders. But it is usually at a substantial performance penalty. It is "hardware accelerated", but it generally won't be at the same speed as 32-bit floats.

But ultimately, its best to just test it and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Nevertheless, I rely more on my personal experience than on dubious sources. Adding "GL_ARB...fp64" does not help to use trigonometric functions with double, which is also written in the OpenGL specification. This is why I am interested in professional solutions. However, some manufacturers write something like "fp32:fp64 - 1:10/5/3" for gaming video cards, and "1:2" for professional ones. So, after all, something is done differently in professional video cards.

Comment: @RomanZuev: "*Adding "GL_ARB...fp64" does not help to use trigonometric functions with double, which is also written in the OpenGL specification.*" You didn't mention double-precision trig functions. Yes, OpenGL doesn't offer those. There is to my knowledge no extension that provides these functions either. So a "professional" card won't help. "*So, after all, something is done differently in professional video cards.*" That's a matter of *performance*, not capabilities.